# Flutter can't find the uid, it returns null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

My app can't find the uid. I think there is a problem about logic. If verification will complete successfully, then it should create uid and write to Firebase.

problem is here: [image]

My codes:

```
Future<void> signInWithTelephoneNumber(context,
      {String phoneNumber, smsCode, codeController}) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber, isInProgress: true, errorMessage: ""));

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: "+9$phoneNumber",
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .signInWithCredential(credential)
            .then((value) async {
          final uid = value.user.uid;
          
          final existingUserDocs = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('Users')
              .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
              .get();

          if (existingUserDocs.docs.isEmpty || existingUserDocs.docs == null) {
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid).set({
              'email': phoneNumber,
              'username': "Deneme User",
              'uid': uid,
              'userPhotoUrl':
                  "https://kulisvar.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sagopa-kajmer-696x465.jpg"
            });
          }
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
        });
      },
```

Comment: did you print uid ?

Comment: i wrote in below

Comment: "My app can't find the uid" What does this mean? When you step through this code in a debugger, which one specific line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes. Firebase user id return null,

Comment: Please be more specific. On what line did you determine that the UID is null when you ran this code in the debugger?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen before logining, we have not user id right? It's okey. I create user id in verificationComplete: part. If verification complete, then i write go home page. When it goes home page, at the same time it has to write its uid which is already created by Firestore (i can see its uid in Firestore in Signed-in part).So it has uid, i can see, but it behaves current user uid is null, it gives this error, also i add img above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add an await before function of creation the user

```
   await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid).set({
                  'email': phoneNumber,
                  'username': "Deneme User",
                  'uid': uid,
                  'userPhotoUrl':
                      "https://kulisvar.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/sagopa-kajmer-696x465.jpg"
                });
```

Comment: i tried but it does not work, it gives still error, also i try change the uid ( i mean first i tried final uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;  this, after that this : value.user.uid;  also i add await, but still same problem

Comment: in which line you have the error, did you print the uid ?

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (18016): #0      UserInfo.uid
package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/user_info.dart:52
E/flutter (18016): #1      UserInfo.toString
package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/user_info.dart:57

Comment: also here uid D/FirebaseAuth(18016): Notifying id token listeners about user ( gBHatfnub1fouPv342CU3MgthRt1 ).